# How to update row that is clicked?

Tags: android, sql, listview, sql-update

After a long time I figured out that changing argument from 0 to different number allows me to update row with corresponding id to this number:

```
private void saveItToDB() {
    dba.open();
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(((TextView) editText).getText().toString(), 2);
    dba.close();
    ((TextView) editText).setText("");
}
```

In above code I changed 0 to 2 and I was able to update content of row no 2. Here is full class code:

```
class EditListItemDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {
MyDB dba;
private View editText;
private DiaryAdapter adapter;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public EditListItemDialog(Context context) {           
    super(context);
    dba = new MyDB(context);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.edit_text_dialog);//here is your xml with EditText and 'Ok' and 'Cancel' buttons
View btnOk = findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
btnOk.setOnClickListener(this);

dba.open();
}

private List<String> fragment_monday;

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//Position is the number of the item clicked
//You can use your adapter to modify the item
adapter.getItem(position); //Will return the clicked item
}

public EditListItemDialog(Context context, DiaryAdapter adapter, int position) {
super(context);
this.fragment_monday = new ArrayList<String>();
this.adapter = adapter;
dba = new MyDB(context);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

fragment_monday.add(((TextView) v).getText().toString());//here is your updated(or not updated) text
dismiss();
try {
    saveItToDB();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

private void saveItToDB() {
    dba.open();
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(((TextView) editText).getText().toString(), 2);
    dba.close();
    ((TextView) editText).setText("");
}



}
```

Now, what do I need to do in order to tell it that I want to update row that is clicked, not row number 2? Any help would be appreciated.

Here is MyDB code:

```
public class MyDB {
private static final String TABLE_NAME = null;
private static final String KEY_ID = null;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private final Context context;
private final MyDBhelper dbhelper;



// Initializes MyDBHelper instance
public MyDB(Context c){

    context = c;
    dbhelper = new MyDBhelper(context, Constants.DATABASE_NAME, null,
                                        Constants.DATABASE_VERSION);

}


// Closes the database connection
public void close()
{
    db.close();

}

// Initializes a SQLiteDatabase instance using MyDBhelper
public void open() throws SQLiteException
{

    try {
        db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    } catch(SQLiteException ex) {
        Log.v("Open database exception caught", ex.getMessage());
        db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    }

}

// updates a diary entry (existing row)
    public boolean updateDiaryEntry(String title, long rowId)
    {

        ContentValues newValue = new ContentValues();
        newValue.put(Constants.TITLE_NAME, title);

        return db.update(Constants.TABLE_NAME, newValue, Constants.KEY_ID + "=" + rowId, null)>0;

    }

// Reads the diary entries from database, saves them in a Cursor class and returns it from the method
public Cursor getdiaries()
{
    Cursor c = db.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME, null, null,
                        null, null, null, null);
    return c;
}


}
```

Here is the Adapter:

```
public class Monday extends ListActivity {


private SQLiteDatabase db;
private static final int MyMenu = 0;
MyDB dba;
DiaryAdapter myAdapter;

private class MyDiary{
    public MyDiary(String t, String c){
        title=t;
        content=c;



}

    public String title;
    public String content;

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    dba = new MyDB(this);
    dba.open();
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_monday);





    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myAdapter = new DiaryAdapter(this);
    this.setListAdapter(myAdapter);
}



public class DiaryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<MyDiary> fragment_monday;
    public DiaryAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        fragment_monday = new ArrayList<MyDiary>();
        getdata();

        ListView list = getListView();
        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    new EditListItemDialog(Monday.this, null, position).show();

                return true;       
            }
        });

    }

    public void getdata(){
        Cursor c = dba.getdiaries();
        startManagingCursor(c);
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                String title =
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.TITLE_NAME));
                String content =
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.CONTENT_NAME));

                MyDiary temp = new MyDiary(title,content);
                fragment_monday.add(temp);
            } while(c.moveToNext());
        }

    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {return fragment_monday.size();}
    public MyDiary getItem(int i) {return fragment_monday.get(i);}
    public long getItemId(int i) {return i;}
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        View v = arg1;
        if ((v == null) || (v.getTag() == null)) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.diaryrow,  null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mTitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name);

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.mdiary = getItem(arg0);
        holder.mTitle.setText(holder.mdiary.title);


        v.setTag(holder);

        return v;


    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        MyDiary mdiary;
        TextView mTitle;


    }

}




/** Called when the user clicks the Edit button */
public void visitDiary(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Diary.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
/** Called when the user clicks the back button */
public void visitSchedule(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayScheduleScreen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement [`getItemId(int position)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemId%28int%29) in your adapter. In your `onListItemClick` method, call this method with the given position.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    long itemId = adapter.getItemId(position);
    saveItToDB(itemId);
}

private void saveItToDB(long itemId) {
    String text = editText.getText().toString();
    editText.setText("");

    dba.open();
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(text, itemId);
    dba.close();
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how to do this, can you help me please?

Comment: You have a class called DiaryAdapter. I presume it extends some kind of ListAdapter (like BaseAdapter)? Override the getItemId method and make it return the ID of the item at the requested position.

Comment: but I already have 'adapter.getItem(position);' , does it make a difference?

Comment: `getItem` one returns an Object, `getItemId` returns a `long`. You can call `getItem` and return some property of that item. Or you can do something else entirely. The point is to implement something that takes a position and gets you back the ID of the item at that position.

Comment: and then I just use position instead of number in saveItToDB?

Comment: Yes, make it take a long parameter and use that instead of the 2.

Comment: I have problems with putting the code in the right place, I get errors wherever I write

Comment: You need the ID of the item you want to update instead of the 2. Do you have a way to get this ID somehow?

Comment: do I not get the id from onItemClick?

Comment: No, that is the item's position in the adapter. The ID is from the database. Does your query include the ID column?

Comment: That and your DiaryAdapter.

Comment: If your table has a column that is a unique ID, then you can easily override `long getItemId(int position)` in the DiaryAdapter, just move the cursor to that position and return the value of the ID column. In the click listener, you call this and use the ID for the save operation instead of the 2 that you have now.

Comment: where exactly in the adapter I should put this code? I get error when I try to override getItemId

Comment: because you already have `public long getItemId(int i) {return i;}` in your adapter

Comment: So I cannot override it then

Comment: can I use i instead of the position then?

Comment: Of course, you can name method parameters anything you like. I think position is much more descriptive about what the parameter should be, but it's really up to you.

Comment: but if I have already getItemId, i should work in saveItToDB or am I wrong?

Comment: You need to **USE** the ID in saveItToDB. Right now you are using `2` in saveItToDB, so you are always saving to the row with ID = 2.

Comment: btw how do I write code in comments? I cannot get it working with ''

Comment: See my edit. Take the position, get the item ID, save the item with that ID. If this isn't what you are trying to do, then I must have misunderstood something.

Comment: I am getting errors at getText and setText that method is undefined for the type View. Adding cast to the editText solves the errors but then the rows in table are not getting updated